# how to initialize an array of type time_t in C?

Tags: c

I do not know how many items can be there in the array. I want to keep storing the output from a loop in this array of type time_t and ultimately get the max of the array members.
Can someone please help me with how to initialize this array or what else can be used in this situation?

Comment: If you just need to get the maximum, just keep a variable ```max``` and compare it with every new value you get in the loop. You don't need to store the values just for that.

Comment: using only one array will be inefficient since you'll have a realloc it often and implementing a custom vector from c++ is a pain. Easiest way if you really want to keep the values is to make an hybrid array/list (like a list of 100 values) which limits the overhead from the list and you can get an array out of it pretty easily in the end if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

i would not use an array, instead the choice of weapons is a single linked list, as described in the bible (The C Programming Language by K&R)

Answer (score 0):

To initialize *any object* to `0` (recursively if needed) use what I like to call the *"universal zero initializer"*

```
time_t array1[1000] = {0};
```

If you want a different value, your best bet is to leave the object uninitialized and afterwards assign its different elements a value

```
time_t array[1000]; /* uninitialized */
for (int k = 0; k < 10000; k++) {
    array[k] = 15439354432 + k; /* assignment */
}
```